# Cocoa Application on remote files?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created a small application that selects the files and renames spaces into underscores and few other symbols. It works fine when I tried with the files on my desktop but it fails to execute when i try with files on my remote server. The problem is it doesn't show any signs of error. In my application, once the files are renamed, I will get a notification on my app stating the number of files renamed. It does show that the file is renamed but I couldn't find the renamed files. Any suggestion as to why it happens or any fixes for this please.

I have created the application and exported as a Mac Executable Application.

Comment: How is the remote server connected?

Comment: I have no idea as it is done by a different person before I join the company. But as always it is a main server that remotely connects all the computers. I never had this forecast for an error but i did all possible tests on my local computer, which worked fine.

Comment: It is fine if there is no solution  but if anyone has used NSFileManager to perform file operations on a remote server files, kindly share your experiences so I will try to decipher something out of it.

Comment: Solved: NSFileManager recognises file paths in different formats so we need to change according to the default path format with which Mac recognises and update files. I changed accordingly and it works. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: NSFileManager recognises file paths in different formats so we need to change according to the default path format with which Mac recognises and update files. I changed accordingly and it works. Thanks for you help.